# 3D image sample frequency

Tags: image-processing, matlab, fft, discrete-signals

I am currently frequency filtering a 3D image in matlab, with x,y,z dimensions of different lengths. The matlab filter takes normalised frequency as an argument. What does this mean for an image and how do I calculate it?

Note : the distance between each pixel is 2mm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 mm period between samples is 500 samples per meter.  That's your sampling frequency.

[Matlab's digital filter design functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/analog-filters.html) (is that what you're using?) take a normalized frequency from 0 to 1, where 1 is the Nyquist frequency (1/2 the sampling frequency; the highest spatial frequency you can measure at that sample rate).

So if you wanted to filter at a spatial frequency of 100 cycles per meter (features that cycle every 1 cm), for instance, you would note that the Nyquist frequency is 250 cycles per meter, and enter a value of 100/250 = **0.4** for the normalized frequency.

Comment: Just to be clear then, does this mean that the smallest distance I can reliably examine with my filter is 1/250=4mm, and not the 2mm of my pixel?

Comment: @user1531177: You can identify features 2 mm wide, such as a pattern where every voxel alternates between light and dark, which has a wavelength (complete cycle of light to dark) of 2 voxels = 4 mm.